# Rails Fragment Caching with nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

My problem with the Fragment Caching is, that I need to perform the Russian Doll caching, which is implemented in Rails, the other way round.

```
class Bundle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #name: string
  belongs_to :product_type
end


class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
  #description: string
end


<!--- views/bundles/show.html.haml >
%table
  %tbody
    = render @bundle.products


<!--- views/products/_product.html.haml >
- cache [product] do
  %tr
    %td= product.name
    - cache [product.product_type] do
      %td= product.product_type.description
```

As you can see, when I update the description of a `ProductType`, then the cache is not refreshed. To my knowledge, the `touch: true` option can only be applied in a `belongs_to` relation and the caching of `product.product_type` is overridden because the cache accesses `product` first.

Is there a good solution to this or will I end up having to update all the corresponding `Products` when a `ProductType` changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails cache\_digests touch has\_many association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078863/rails-cache-digests-touch-has-many-association)